# How to display a result with many decimal points

Tags: java

i am trying to display a result but it is just returning 0, even though if you calculate the answer it is not zero but needs more decimal points after the zero

the code :

```
                long transferRate = ((len*2) / durationseconds ) ; //amount of data in bytes transferred in 1 second. Currently returning 0 for every result
                System.out.println("transferRate: " + transferRate + " bytes per second");
```

is the part i need to return an answer to many decimal places, how can i specify this ?

because currently it is displaying results :

```
Time for the ping to be sent and recived of 2 bytes is 365636931 seconds
transferRate: 0 bytes per second
Time for the ping to be sent and recived of 4 bytes is 43375591 seconds
transferRate: 0 bytes per second
Time for the ping to be sent and recived of 8 bytes is 51079641 seconds
transferRate: 0 bytes per second
Time for the ping to be sent and recived of 16 bytes is 54751211 seconds
transferRate: 0 bytes per second
Time for the ping to be sent and recived of 32 bytes is 57195731 seconds
transferRate: 0 bytes per second
Time for the ping to be sent and recived of 64 bytes is 48524461 seconds
transferRate: 0 bytes per second
Time for the ping to be sent and recived of 128 bytes is 51243251 seconds
transferRate: 0 bytes per second
```

Thanks

Comment: `long` doesn't store floating point numbers. You need a `float` or `double`.

Comment: Thanks i have tried them but they only give a result 0.0, is there anyway to display more results after the decimal point

Comment: the righthand side of your operation needs to be double, too. Just as in Doorknob's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
long transferRate = ((len*2) / durationseconds ) ;
```

You can't store a decimal in a `long`. Try:

```
double transferRate = ((len*2) / (double) durationseconds ) ;
```

You must cast one of the operands to a `double` because otherwise you will still be doing integer division anyway.

For example, `1 / 2` would evaluate to `0`. However, `1 / 2.0` would be `0.5`.